# Como consumir WebService da PrefeituraSP para NFS-e Erro "cliente 'Anonymous'" VB.NET

Tags: web-service, vb.net

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que irá enviar XMLs ao WS da receita federal, fiz a referencia usando o seguinte URL: https://nfe.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/ws/lotenfe.asmx

Mas quando passa pela Função de Teste `EnvioRPS()` da o seguinte erro:
  *"A solicitação HTTP está proibida com o esquema de autenticação de cliente 'Anonymous'"*

**Para fazer um teste com o WS estou fazendo o seguinte, em um Evento Button_Click :**

```
    Dim WS As New WebServiceNFSE_TESTE.LoteNFeSoapClient

    Dim Busca As X509Certificate2 = Buscar_Certificado_Nome("")

    'Teste
    MessageBox.Show(WS.EnvioRPS(1, ""))
```

**Função que busca o certificado:**

```
 Public Shared Function Buscar_Certificado_Nome(_nm_certificado As String) As X509Certificate2
    Dim X509_certificado As New X509Certificate2()
    Dim X509_store As New X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
    X509_store.Open(OpenFlags.[ReadOnly] Or OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly Or OpenFlags.IncludeArchived)
    Dim X509_collection0 As X509Certificate2Collection = DirectCast(X509_store.Certificates, X509Certificate2Collection)
    Dim X509_collection1 As X509Certificate2Collection = DirectCast(X509_collection0.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, False), X509Certificate2Collection)
    Dim X509_collection2 As X509Certificate2Collection = DirectCast(X509_collection0.Find(X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage, X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, False), X509Certificate2Collection)

    If _nm_certificado = "" Then
        Dim scollection As X509Certificate2Collection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(X509_collection2, "Certificado(s) Digital(is) disponível(is)", "Selecione o Certificado Digital para uso no aplicativo", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)
        If scollection.Count = 0 Then
            'Nenhum certificado escolhido
            X509_certificado.Reset()
        Else
            X509_certificado = scollection(0)
        End If
    Else
        Dim scollection As X509Certificate2Collection = X509_collection1.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "ce c9 ed 7a b6 54 fe fe 1b bf 31 78 ef 5f 74 be be 6e e8 12", True)
        If scollection.Count = 0 Then
            'Nenhum certificado válido foi encontrado com o nome informado
            X509_certificado.Reset()
        Else
            X509_certificado = scollection(0)
        End If
    End If
    X509_store.Close()
    Return X509_certificado
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Fazendo um Binding Customizado da seguinte forma, consegui consumir o WS e ter o retorno usando o seguinte código:

```
        Dim Certificado As X509Certificate2
    Dim WS As WebServiceNFSE_TESTE.LoteNFeSoapClient

    Dim httpstransport As New ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement

    Try
        Certificado = Buscar_Certificado_Nome("")
        httpstransport.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard
        httpstransport.ManualAddressing = False
        httpstransport.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288
        httpstransport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536
        httpstransport.AllowCookies = False
        httpstransport.BypassProxyOnLocal = False
        httpstransport.KeepAliveEnabled = True
        httpstransport.MaxBufferSize = 65536
        httpstransport.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered
        httpstransport.UnsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication = True
        httpstransport.UseDefaultWebProxy = True
        httpstransport.RequireClientCertificate = True

        Dim MessageEncoding As New TextMessageEncodingBindingElement()
        MessageEncoding.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12
        MessageEncoding.WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
        MessageEncoding.MaxReadPoolSize = 64
        MessageEncoding.MaxWritePoolSize = 16

        Dim CustomBinding As New ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding(MessageEncoding, httpstransport)

        Dim uri As String() = {"https://nfe.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/ws/lotenfe.asmx"}
        Dim EndpointAddress As New ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(uri(0))

         WS = New WebServiceNFSE_TESTE.LoteNFeSoapClient(CustomBinding, EndpointAddress)
         WS.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = Certificado

        Dim oXml As New XmlDocument
        oXml.Load("C:\PedidoEnvioRPS.xml")

         MsgBox(WS.EnvioRPS(1, oXml.InnerText))

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```